# Data type for Function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

component1.tsx

```
const handleAnalytics = (analyticEvent: SimpleUiEvent) => {
    DataCollection.sendEvent(analyticEvent);
};


<Component2
    key={flippingCard.title}
    triggerAnalytics={() => handleAnalytics(flippingCard.analyticEvent)}
    {...flippingCard}
/>
```

component2.tsx

```
const handleTileFlip = () => {
    if (triggerAnalytics) {
        props.triggerAnalytics(); **// This is giving error here "Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)**
        setTriggerAnalytics(false);
    }
    setIsFlipped(!isFlipped);
};
```

**interface**

```
export interface Component2Props {
    title: string;
    subTitle: string;
    icon?: React.ReactNode;
    content: string;
    triggerAnalytics?: () => void; **// Not sure what comes here**
}
```

Tried couple of things but no success. Also tried "Function" as well. Basically my question is what would be the data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type is right.

The problem is that the triggerAnalytics prop is optional, but you're invoking it as if it's guaranteed to be defined.

If you're always going to be passing triggerAnalytics, then get rid of the optional (question mark) in the component2props interface.

Or check that it's defined before calling it in your handle function.